# How to keep telnet connection alive from client side

Tags: linux, terminal, telnet

I have a device as a telnet server but drops the connection if no packet is received in 60 seconds, for some reason this behavior cannot be changed. Putty has a feature to send null packets to the server periodically to keep the session alive, which works fine for me. But some times I have to telnet to the device from linux terminal, where putty is not available. So I wonder if it's possible to periodically send null packets with the linux telnet client, or any other way to keep the session alive, or other command line telnet client that could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but might suffice. Wrap the telnet within an expect script that detects lack of input. It sends the escape sequence <kbd>control-]</kbd> to the telnet client to get the command prompt `telnet>`, and issues the command `send nop` (no-operation). I assume this is enough to keep the connection alive. If not there are other commands to try.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet localhost 
expect "ogin: "
send "username\r"
expect "assword:"
send "mypw\r"
expect {$ }
interact timeout 10 {
 log_user 0; send "\x1d"; expect "telnet>" { send "send nop\r" };
 expect "send nop\r\n"; log_user 1 }
```

Obviously, you need to edit this with the desired hostname, username, password, and expected command prompt. See `man expect` for the syntax.

Comment: How about when the server side runs a screen session with sime interactive stuff like mc or irssi? Can we modify it somehow? Maybe use some text from the TUI instead of telnet>?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are seeing. In principle the script above should work transparently, i.e. neither the remote server nor the local client should see the short added transaction. The "telnet>" string is sent by the local telnet client, and the use of `log_user 0` should stop `expect` from printing this out to the local terminal. The remote server should receive a low-level telnet protocol packet with the "nop" command, to which it should not reply, nor pass on to whatever is running there, like `mc`.

Comment: What is meant by "not perfect"? What happens if the user types characters in between sending the telnet escape character (`\x1d`) and the `send nop`? Does expect buffer them and send them after `log_user 1`?

Comment: Why does this script hardcode the hostname instead of using `$argv`? Is there some nuance of TCL I don't understand? And, wouldn't it be better to not hardcode the username and password, or is that required for this technique to work?

Comment: @hackerb9 tcl is single threaded by default, so user input should not be read whilst the timeout block is being executed; however, data coming in from the remote might be swallowed up by the `expect "telnet>"`. It depends how the telnet client program reacts to receiving the escape char; will it immediately send the prompt, or will it flush any incoming remote data first? Of course, there is no need to hardcode username and password; the point is to keep the script as simple as possible avoiding distractions.

Answer (score 1):

With the command line telnet client that's not possible. You can enable frequent TCP keepalives globally: [TCP Keepalive HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html). I don't know if this has any side-effects, but it seems like a viable workaround.

By the way, putty is available on Linux. You just need to have an X server on your machine to run it on a remote host (I assume you're ssh-ing into the Linux box where you do your telnet work). If you're on Windows, the Linux Subsystem for Windows together with an X server might do the trick. Cygwin also works for this.

Answer (score 1):

## libkeepalive

### TL;DR

```
apt install libkeepalive0                 # Only needed once
export KEEPIDLE=1 KEEPINTVL=10 
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libkeepalive.so telnet gaia.local
```

### Explanation

Telnet uses TCP ("Transmission Control Protocol") to communicate with the server. TCP implementations on most UNIX systems allow programs to request that a connection be [kept alive](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/programming.html). While BSD has a nice way of handling this if a program does not enable keepalive on its own, it appears Linux requires a little bit of a kludge: wrap the program in [`libkeepalive`](https://libkeepalive.sourceforge.net/) using LD_PRELOAD so that the TCP socket calls are altered before going to the kernel.

### Installation

You can compile libkeepalive from https://libkeepalive.sourceforge.net/. You do not need to be root to use it. However, it is easier on most GNU/Linux distributions to install it from the package manager. For example, on Debian and Ubuntu, one could do `apt install libkeepalive0`.

### Variables

There are three environment variables which control how libkeepalive works. The variables are documented in the Linux [manpage for tcp](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/manpages/tcp.7.en.html#TCP_KEEPCNT)(7).

| Variable name | /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ | Meaning | Default | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `KEEPIDLE` | tcp_keepalive_time | Interval between last data packet sent and first keepalive probe | 7200 | seconds |
| `KEEPINTVL` | tcp_keepalive_intvl | Interval between subsequent keepalive probes | 75 | seconds |
| `KEEPCNT` | tcp_keepalive_probes | Consider connection dead if this many probes are sent to the server without receiving a response | 9 | count |

### Caveat

There can be multiple causes for a server to drop an idle connection. This keepalive solution only operates at the level of TCP packets. It would not work if the telnetd on your server is looking for user keystrokes or telnet packets (`SEND NOP`).